# Recurrent exception in Delphi TService on W10 and Server 2012r2

Tags: delphi, service, access-violation

I am working on a Delphi application using the TService functionalities.
It is a large project that was started by someone else.
The application uses several separate threads for processing, communicating with clients, database access, etc. The application’s main job is to poll regularly (every 2-300ms) certain devices and, a couple times a day, execute specific actions.
Now somewhere there is an unhandled exception for which I cannot seem to find the cause:

[image: xe5-err]

According to the debugger, the faulting method is **System.Classes.StdWndProc**.
This also seems to be confirmed by analyzing the crash dump file with WinDbg.

[image: xe5-dbg]

After numerous tests and debugging, I noticed that the crash happened on my dev computer every day at almost the same time.
I looked at the windows log and found this event:

[image: win-el]

This, coupled with the fact that the stack trace from Delphi indicates that a message with ID=26 (**WM_WININICHANGE**) was processed, made me believe that there might be something wrong with my usage of **FormatDateTime()** or **DateTimeToStr()** when regional settings are reloaded.
I checked every call and made sure to be using the thread-safe overload with a local instance of **TFormatSettings**.
However today the service crashed again.

A few points that I think are worth mentioning:

- The application is also installed on a Windows 2008 server and has
  been running OK for over a month.
- On 2012r2 I tried forcing DEP off, but it didn’t change anything.
- The service’s OnExecute() method is not implemented. I create a base    thread in TService. ServiceStart() which then in turn creates the main data module and all the other threads.
- The service is not marked as interactive and is executed with the    Local System account.
- All data modules are created with AOwner=nil.
- With a special parameter, the application can be started a normal    windowed application with a main form (which is created only in this    case). **The exception does not seem to happen when running in GUI mode**.
- Almost all threads have a message pump and use PostThreadMessage() to exchange information. There are no window handle allocations anywhere.
- I have checked the whole project and there are no timers or message dialogs or other graphical components anywhere.
- I have activated range as well as overflow checking and found no issues.

I am a loss for what to do here. I have checked and re-checked the code several times without finding anything that could explain the error.

Looking online I found several reports that seem to be pertinent to my situation, but none that actually explains what is going on:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-group-policy-application-hang/72016ea4-ba89-4770-b1de-6ddf14b0a51f

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20720591/Prevent-regional-settings-from-changing-inside-a-TService-class.html

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=832265

Before taking everything apart I would like to know if anyone experienced anything similar or has any tips.

Thanks

**Edit:** looking at the call stack and the first method executed I am thinking of the TApplication instance that is used in TService.

Comment: You are using Vcl.Forms.TApplication,
remove all references to Vcl.Forms and use Vcl.SvcMgr.TApplication.

Comment: I looked at the implementation for TService and noticed that TServiceApplication itself calls **Vcl.Forms.Application.HookMainWindow()** in its constructor.  Furthermore in the dpr's uses clause Vcl.SvcMgr comes **after** Vcl.Forms plus I always use the full Vcl.SvcMgr.Application when calling instance, exactly as what is done in the template service application in RAD Studio.

Comment: No need to 'take everything apart'. Copy the service to a 'dummy' one that mimics your original. Make it so that it does as much data processing as possible that does not change states (e.g. pull input but don't write output to a database). Have this run in parallel. No errors? -> it's the disabled code. Errors -> Comment out parts of the code and rerun.

Comment: After further inspection of the full crash dump file I noticed that the exception occurs in the context (thread ID) as the one that executes TService.ServiceCreate. And according to the documentation, it is the main application thread.  
Why would there be messages sent to it instead of the service thread?

Comment: Every time the exception is raised (once a day on my dev machine) LPARAM is always 648680. Still trying to figure out who allocates a window that gets destoyed at some point..

Answer (score 0):

> LPARAM is always 648680.

LPARAM is a pointer to a string (you can cast it to PChar).

You could try to catch WM_SETTINGS_CHANGE and log anytime it's processing.

I think you could use TApplicationEvents component. The component has OnSettingsChange event. The event provides a setting area name (section name) and a flag that points to changed parameter.

Have a look at [doc-wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Forms.TSettingChangeEvent).
There is a full list of possible parameters.

I did not test it, but maybe you can use Abort procedure in OnSettingsChange event handler to stop the message distribution. Of course it's not a solution, but it may work.